# Free groups of rank greater than 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I'm trying show that a free group of rank $\ge2$ is non abelian, but I have no idea to prove this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your definition of free group?

Comment: Take the normal form of an element in a free group freely generated by $\;\{x,y,\ldots\}\;$ . Then, $\;xy\neq yx\;$

Comment: $F$ is a free group on generators $X$ iff for any group $G$ and any function $f:X\rightarrow G$, exist a unique homomorphism $\theta_f:F\rightarrow G$ that extends $f$.

Comment: what is a normal form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.**  Pick your favourite non-commutative group, say $G$, and two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ in the basis $X$.  You can define a function $f$ from $X$ to $G$ that sends $x$ and $y$ to non-commuting elements in $G$, sending the rest of $X$ to (e.g.) $1\in G$.  This extends to a homomorphism from $F$ to $G$.  Use this to show that $x$ and $y$ do not commute.